# phpmyadmin login redirects to same login page

Tags: php, mysql, lamp

I tried reading all related questions and man page too. But no luck. I am unable to login to phpmyadmin page in my browser. cli works fine for mysql. and even php scripts are well run and executed. whenever i login to phpmyadmin/index.php i am not taken further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had this issue, for me the root cause appears to have been disk full.  Deleted some log files and phpMyAdmin is Ok again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clearing your browser cache, or opening it in different browsers? PMA tends to bug on that.