# how to clear server/host log

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, lamp

Suddenly my phpmyadmin page can't load and redirect to the same login page, although I can login to mysql through shell, I tried to clear the cache of the browser and still have this issue. I read in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7252456/phpmyadmin-login-redirects-to-same-login-page) to clear the server/host log files and I search in google 'how to do that' and I find the log files was at /var/log folder, but I don't know which files is can be delete, I'm afraid to lost my data in mysql. I'm running server with lamp. Which log files exactly should I delete?

Comment: do you run it on your local machine?

Comment: Nope, I run it in amazon ec2 ubuntu server

Comment: I guess there should be a control panel where you can check remaining free space. Try to clear all cookies for phpmyadmin.

Comment: ok, I think you are right, I was clear the log files and still have this issue, how to check that (cookies for phpmyadmin)? I dont have control panel, I run it with shell

Comment: what browser do you use? In Chrome you can manage cookies under "Advanced settings".

Comment: I have clean it, and set to clear phpmyadmin on exit, but still have this issue.

Comment: Try to log in in another browser.

Comment: It still, I've tried in IE and Mozilla

Comment: Wierd. Did you logged in into phpmyadmin with IE and Mozilla previously? Did you install phpmyadmin yourself? Also you can try incognito mode in Chrome.

Comment: I didn't logged in with IE and Mozilla before, Yes, I do it myself, but I've never changes any configurations, it still defaults setting, I don't know how to run in incognito mode, anyway, I've opened this issue on this new post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16679884/phpmyadmin-cant-login-with-no-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no mysql data in /var/log, just log files, so you can't lose any data.

Delete a bunch of the older *.gz files. These are log files from previous weeks or months, depending on how many old files you keep during rotation. You should also update your logrotate configuration files to reduce the number of old files you save, so you don't fill up the disk again.

Comment: Thanks, can you give me good references or link how to update logrotate configuration files?

Comment: They're located in /etc/logrotate.d. Read `man logrotate` for information on the options.

Comment: Thanks, I still have the issue after clear all log files with gz extension, what is wrong with my phpmyadmin, are you have other solutions?

Comment: I don't know anything about phpmyadmin. I was just answering your question about deleting log files. I assumed you already verified that running out of disk space was the problem.

Comment: Alright then, Thanks for your helps man, I'll post this issue on new questions.